# Atualizar atividade após deslizar do dedo na tela

Tags: android, android-layout

Como que faço para atualiza a atividade da APP depois que o usuário deslizar o dedo na tela para baixo. Como detectar está ação para poder disparar um evento no meu código?

Comment: Você poderia usar o [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) que está presente na **support-library-v4**.

Comment: Olá Wakim! Agradecia que coloca-se um exemplo de uso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar o `SwipeRefreshLayout` é bem simples.

#### 0 - Configuração

Se ainda não utilizar a **Support Library v4**, então adicione a mesma ao seu projeto:

```
dependencies {
    // Demais dependencias do seu projeto
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

Caso não use o **Gradle**, então é preciso importar a **Support Library v4** seguindo esse tutorial: [support-library/setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

#### 1 - Adicione o `SwipeRefreshLayout` como raiz do seu layout.

Um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Restante das views do seu layout -->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

#### 2 - Na sua `Activity` ou `Fragment`, configure o `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
// Recupera o SwipeRefreshLayout
mSwipeToRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_container);

// Seta o Listener para atualizar o conteudo quando o gesto for feito
mSwipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);

// O esquema de cores
mSwipeToRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(
    R.color.indigo_300,
    R.color.indigo_400,
    R.color.indigo_500,
    R.color.indigo_600,
    R.color.indigo_700,
    R.color.indigo_800,
    R.color.indigo_900
);
```

#### 3 - Executar a ação quando o `SwipeRefreshLayout` notificar:

Sua Activity deve implementar a interface [`SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener.html).

```
@Override 
public void onRefresh() {
    // Executar a atualizacao
}
```

#### 4 - Finalizar a animação quando os dados forem carregados:

```
mSwipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: Olá Wakim! Obrigado pelo exemplo, só que mesmo assim não estou a conseguir construir um exemplo. Podia-me enviar um projecto já pronto para o Eclipse?

Comment: @VitorMendanha, infelizmente não uso mais o Eclipse a muito tempo, posso tentar mais tarde construir um exemplo funcional. Mas seria mais rápido talvez você ir acrescentando a pergunta os erros que esta tendo, para chegar na solução.

Comment: Vou testar com o Android Studio. Obrigado.